# Gifs in Notification Service Extension crashing

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, ios10, notificationservices

I'm trying to implement Notification Service extension, I was able to use it for images, audio and videos. But in Gifs, for few of the gifs the extension is crashing. eg. I tried for this attachment url which crashed my extension : https://g.twimg.com/blog/blog/image/Taco_Party_0.gif

I'm saving the downloaded gif in temporary folder and then creating an `UNNotificationAttachment` instance. The instance isn't nil and also I checked the type of attachment to confirm, and it gave me `com.compuserve.gif`. Its not happening for all the gifs, but I found this issue in multiple cases.

I'm getting `Program ended with exit code: 0` in the console.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

I tried Rich Notifications with your gif attachment and got the same error.
just extracted your gif and I found 222 frames!!
you please try with some other gif with lesser frames say below 50,
I tried and it is working.

Comment: I have tried gifs with lesser frames, it work's fine. The gif which I'm talking about work's sometimes. It's random, sometimes it doesn't crash, but most of the time it crashes. I have submitted a bug report, Apple support has replied saying they are investigating the issue. All I want to know is when does the extension crash, so that we I can avoid using such gifs.

Comment: gif with above particular frame will crash.

Comment: It did work in iPod Touch and iPhone6S few times for me, thats why I said its not crashing everytime.